# Removing duplicates in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
dict_list = [
    {"Module": abc, "Error": dgh, "Count": 12, Time: "kabs"},
    {"Module": abc, "Error": dgh, "Count": 3, Time: "askdj"},
    {"Module": aea, "Error": adsaw, "Count": 4, Time: "asna"
]
```

As you can see each dictionary has the same unique keys but same or different values. There can be instances where the values of `dict2["Modules"] == dict1["Modules"]` and `dict2["Errors"] == dict1["Errors"]` with other key values different as shown in the example.
This instance is called a duplicate. I want to remove the duplicate dictionary from the list but increase the count of the remaining one.

Comment: You've described your goal fairly well. What precisely is keeping you from your goal? What have you tried so far? How has that failed?

Comment: also, when you post dummy data, try to make it match your needs, because counts having strings as values is not the best example

Comment: It would be good to include an example output as well. With the current question, we have no idea which (if either) time should be kept.

Comment: Also, what do the Module and Error keys contain? If they contain immutable types (like strings), the solution may be a lot more simple than if they do not.

Answer (score 1):

With the given information, this problem is only half-answerable. If what is contained in the `Module` and `Error` keys are hashable (e.g. strings), they can be used as the key of a dictionary. You can construct an intermediate dictionary that has a tuple `(Module, Error)` as a unique key and check for it's existence. If it doesn't exist, store the dictionary. If it does exist, increment `Count`. Then, the values of this dictionary will contain the unique entries of the original list with accumulated counts.

```
def merge_and_sum_counts(list_of_dictionaries):
    tupled_dictionary = {}

    for d in list_of_dictionaries:
        key = (d['Module'], d['Error'])

        if key not in tupled_dictionary:
            tupled_dictionary[key] = d
        else:
            tupled_dictionary[key]['Count'] += d['Count']

    return tupled_dictionary.values()
```

Note that this function does not care about what `Time` remains in each dictionary (since you didn't mention it). Example usage is given below.

```
list_of_dictionaries = [
    {'Module': 'A', 'Error': 'A', 'Count': 5, 'Time': '22:34'},
    {'Module': 'A', 'Error': 'A', 'Count': 3, 'Time': '21:33'},
    {'Module': 'A', 'Error': 'B', 'Count': 2, 'Time': '15:31'},
    {'Module': 'B', 'Error': 'A', 'Count': 1, 'Time': '07:59'},
    {'Module': 'B', 'Error': 'A', 'Count': 7, 'Time': '10:45'},
    {'Module': 'B', 'Error': 'B', 'Count': 9, 'Time': '15:45'},
]

print merge_and_sum_counts(list_of_dictionaries)

# [{'Count': 8, 'Time': '07:59', 'Module': 'B', 'Error': 'A'}, 
#  {'Count': 2, 'Time': '15:31', 'Module': 'A', 'Error': 'B'}, 
#  {'Count': 8, 'Time': '22:34', 'Module': 'A', 'Error': 'A'}, 
#  {'Count': 9, 'Time': '15:45', 'Module': 'B', 'Error': 'B'}]
```

Also, note that this places the existing dictionary objects into a new list. Meaning, the dictionaries in the original list will be updated after running this function. To avoid this, you could change `tupled_dictionary[key] = d` to `tupled_dictionary[key] = d.copy()`.

This approach may also work if `Module` and `Error` are not hashable because tuples themselves are. However, you're going to want to make sure that `Module1 == Module2` returns the value that you expect it to. If `Module` doesn't override the default class `__eq__` function, then equality only exists down to the object `id`. (Which may be what you want, it's hard to say.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need:

```
no_duplicates = {}
for d in dict_list:
    k = (d["Module"], d["Error"])

    if k in no_duplicates:
        no_duplicates[k]["Count"] += d['Count']
    else:
        no_duplicates[k] = d  # or d.copy() if you need to keep d untouched

no_duplicates = no_duplicates.values()
```

Comment: I think there needs to be a debate about whether `key in` or `key not in` is preferable.

Comment: I would use `not in` if I had to modify d before setting it as value of k, but in this case, we increase the count on k already present, hence my approach. I have just added the `d.copy()` because I also wonder if he needs to preserve his initial list values.

Comment: However, as we both answered at the same time, but you answer is more detailed, I would recommend to OP to vote for yours but to use my if / else ;-)

Comment: I stand by my `if/else` but I don't think I have a better reason than "I personally think about the default case first." Either way, if two people independently come to also identical code, it's good evidence to suggest that it may be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably do the job.

```
no_duplicates = {}
for d in dict_list:
    # Generate your unique key
    k = (d["Module"], d["Error"])
    try:
        # Add if already exists.
        no_duplicates[k]["Count"] += 1
    except KeyError:
        # Create a new one if not.
        no_duplicates[k] = d
        d["Count"] = 1

# Generate the new list (Works for python 2 and 3)
no_duplicates_list = list(no_duplicates.values())
```

You create a new dictionary of no duplicates and make the key the values you wish to not have duplicates of. For example `(d["Module"], d["Error"])`. Then, if it already exists, you increase the count. If not, you create a new entry in the dictionary.

If however, you have more new keys than duplicates, this will be more efficient as less exceptions will be thrown:

```
no_duplicates = {}

for d in dict_list:
    k = (d["Module"], d["Error"])
    # Set count to 0
    d["Count"] = 0
    # Set and increase count at once
    no_duplicates.setdefault(k, d)["Count"] += 1

no_duplicates_list = list(no_duplicates.values())
```

**UPDATE:**

If you do not wish to reset the count, here's the code:

```
no_duplicates = {}

for d in dict_list:
    # Generate your unique key
    k = (d["Module"], d["Error"])
    try:
        # Add if already exists.
        no_duplicates[k]["Count"] += d["Count"]
    except KeyError:
        # Create a new one if not.
        no_duplicates[k] = d

# Generate the new list (Works for python 2 and 3)
no_duplicates_list = list(no_duplicates.values())
```

or

```
no_duplicates = {}

for d in dict_list:
    k = (d["Module"], d["Error"])
    # Set and increase count at once
    no_duplicates.setdefault(k, d)["Count"] += 1

no_duplicates_list = list(no_duplicates.values())
```

Comment: This just increments `Count` by 1 rather than adding them together.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at pandas, because what you want is nearly a database opération :

with :

```
dict_list=[{'Time': 'kabs', 'Count': 12, 'Error': 1, 'Module': 1},
 {'Time': 'askdj', 'Count': 3, 'Error': 1, 'Module': 1},
 {'Time': 'asna', 'Count': 4, 'Error': 2, 'Module': 2}]
```

`pandas.DataFrame(dict_list).groupby(['Module','Error'])['Count'].sum()` gives:

```
Module  Error
1       1        15
2       2         4
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list_d = [{"Module":'abc',"Error":'dgh',"Count":'fff','Time':"kabs"},
    {"Module":'abc',"Error":'dgh',"Count":'adak','Time':"askdj"},
    { "Module":'aea',"Error":'adsaw',"Count":'asa','Time':"asna"}]
no_duplicate = {}

for index, d in enumerate(list_d):
    key = d['Module'].lower() +'-'+ d['Error'].lower()
    if key not in no_duplicate:
        no_duplicate[key] = [index,1]
    else:
         no_duplicate[key][1] += 1

output = []
for key,value in no_duplicate.items():
    index = value[0]
    count = value[1]
    if count >=2:
        list_d[index]['count'] = count
    output.append(list_d[index])
print output
```